# Cómo puedo obtener la ram de una VPS OpenVZ?

Tags: java

Estoy creando algunas vps con OpenVZ y me preguntaba cómo puedo obtener la cantidad de RAM de cada vps que tengo.  Es posible mediante java o usando algún comando?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Desde java tenés la clase `Runtime` con la que podes obtener la memoria total y/o disponible que tiene la jvm (virtual machine) que estás ejecutando.

Además cuenta con una serie de métodos `exec`, que te permiten hacer llamadas al Sistema Operativo y recibir la salida del comando como si la hubieras escrito en una terminal.

Asumo que estas usando Linux.

El siguiente programa corre el comando `free -b -w` y parsea el resultado guandándo los diferentes valores en un `HashMap`. Los resultados son en bytes (`-b`), vos podes ver el `man` de `free` y cambiar el programa a tu gusto.

Salida de `free -b -w`:

```
              total usado libre compartido búferes caché disponible
Memoria:  6077865984  1656201216  2569695232    31150080   141312000  1710657536  4101779456
Swap:    5999947776           0  5999947776
```

Programa:

En el programa `labels` tiene los nombres de las columnas y `memTypes` los valores por cada "tipo" de memoria que reporta `free` (En el ejemplo de arriba serian "Memoria" y "Swap").

Los `System.out.println()` muestran como acceder a los valores.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class Memory {
    // total usado libre compartido búferes caché disponible
    private static final String MEM_TOTAL = "total";
    private static final String MEM_USED = "used";
    private static final String MEM_FREE = "free";
    private static final String MEM_SHARED = "shared";
    private static final String MEM_BUFFERES = "bufferes";
    private static final String MEM_CACHE = "cache";
    private static final String MEM_AVAILABLE = "available";

    private static HashMap<String, String> labels = new HashMap<>();
    private static HashMap<String, Map<String,String>> memTypes= new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        try {
            Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process p = r.exec("free -b -w");
            p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            int c = -1;
            String line = reader.readLine();    
            String [] cols = line.split("\\s+");
            labels.put(MEM_TOTAL, cols[1]);
            labels.put(MEM_USED, cols[2]);
            labels.put(MEM_FREE, cols[3]);
            labels.put(MEM_SHARED, cols[4]);
            labels.put(MEM_BUFFERES, cols[5]);
            labels.put(MEM_CACHE, cols[6]);
            labels.put(MEM_AVAILABLE, cols[7]);

            line = reader.readLine();
            while( line != null) {
                cols = line.split("\\s+");
                HashMap<String, String> values = new HashMap<>();
                if(cols.length > 1) values.put(MEM_TOTAL, cols[1]);
                if(cols.length > 2) values.put(MEM_USED, cols[2]);
                if(cols.length > 3) values.put(MEM_FREE, cols[3]);
                if(cols.length > 4) values.put(MEM_SHARED, cols[4]);
                if(cols.length > 5) values.put(MEM_BUFFERES, cols[5]);
                if(cols.length > 6) values.put(MEM_CACHE, cols[6]);
                if(cols.length > 7) values.put(MEM_AVAILABLE, cols[7]);
                memTypes.put(cols[0].replace(":", ""), values);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }

            memTypes.keySet().forEach(new Consumer<String>(){

                @Override
                public void accept(String tipoMemoria) {
                    System.out.println("Para " + tipoMemoria);
                    System.out.println(labels.get(MEM_TOTAL) + ": " + memTypes.get(tipoMemoria).get(MEM_TOTAL) + " bytes");
                    System.out.println(labels.get(MEM_AVAILABLE) + ": " + memTypes.get(tipoMemoria).get(MEM_AVAILABLE) + " bytes");
                }

            });


        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Entiendo lo que me dices, pero creo que me expliqué mal, yo lo que quiero hacer es, imagina que tengo 4 vps, y desde un mismo programa obtener la ram y cpu gastada por las 4vps, y si, utilizo Linux.

Comment: Desde java me parece que esto es lo mejor que vas a poder hacer. Me refiero a correr un proceso en el Sistema Operativo con `Runtime#exec()`. Por ahí vos tenés otro comando (que se corre desde la consola) que te da la info que necesitas. En ese caso podes adaptar el programa para correr ese comando y parsear el resultado.

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias, seguiré investigando a ver si consigo obtener el de las 5 a la vez.